# Databrick - Reading BLOB from Mounted filestorage

Tags: azure-databricks

I am using Azure databricks and I ran the following Python code:

```
sas_token = "<my sas key>"
dbutils.fs.mount(
      source = "wasbs://<container>@<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net",
      mount_point = "/mnt/gl",
      extra_configs = {"fs.azure.sas.<container>.<storageaccount>.blob.core.windows.net": sas_token})
```

This seemed to run fine. So I then ran:

```
df = spark.read.text("/mnt/gl/glAgg_LE.csv")
```

Which gave me the error:

```
shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong though. I'm pretty sure my sas key is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you are getting this error - double check both the SAS key and the container name.
Turned out I had pointed it to the wrong container!